# Increase arrow symbol length by value in Arcmap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, symbology

I use ArcMap to visualize surface displacements. I have a point shapefile with magnitude and angle values, which I plot as simple symbols with size=magnitude and rotation=angle.

As symbol I use arrows which length should increase at higher magnitudes. Anyone have an idea to realize that? My arrows increase in size but I didn't find a method for increasing the length only.

[image]

As you can see the size of arrows change with magnitude. I want that all arrows have the same size and only change in length.

Comment: Can you edit your question and include a image of the current arrow symbol and what you want it to look like?

Comment: I'm not sure that this can be done, but before I suggest ArcGIS Ideas, can you let us know precisely what symbol you are using to place arrows on point features, please?  A screenshot from the Symbol Selector may be the easiest way to do this.